# Calculate RFM in CiviCRM

Tags: contacts, contributions

there is a way or an extension to calculate the RFM (Recency, Frequency and Monetary) score for the contacts, and maybe to store them in the DB.
I read that SmartGroup can be used with this purpose, but after some tests, I cannot figure how.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom report template for that! We have written donor segmentation reports with all kinds of metrics - RFM is just another set of metrics/calculations;

This is still a really good reference to get started on custom reports: https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/civicrm-creating-a-custom-report/

Comment: Wonderful! Thank's a lot

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

iXiam has developed a [custom extension](https://www.ixiam.com/en/rfm-analysis-for-civicrm/) to segment based on the RFM variables you set. This creates clusters to allow you to identify what type of donors the organization has and its evolution via a cluster movement report.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the Summary Fields extensions, which you can find [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields), and which provides fields for contacts including

- Total Lifetime Contributions
- Total Contributions this Year
- Total Contributions last Year
- Amount of Last Contribution
- Date of Last Contribution
- Date of First Contribution
- Largest Contribution
- Count of Contributions
- Average Annual (Calendar Year) Contribution

Comment: Summary Fields extension is excellent - we use it - but RFM scores (I had to look it up as I've never had a request for them) require a bit more math: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFM_(customer_value)

Comment: yes, i expected so  but was hoping Summary Fields may be something you can calculate based on and save some steps. also aware that clients, or consultants to them, often through in new fandangled requests that they scooped off somewhere without really looking at what they can easily get and do some analysis on ;-) afaik RFM still requires decisions on what the criteria should be that need calculating, ie it isn't a single fixed recipe for all occasions/clients but should be adjusted to match their business. good luck, keen to hear how you get on. Also Summary Fields may give you big pointers